# "Could not find IBMIM.exe" error when trying to install a Rational App

Tags: installation, rft

When I try to install Rational Functional Tester (RFT), I get this error. It was installed in this system before; our CMS group has run an uninstall script for RAD, which I guess hard deleted Installation Manager and RFT too.

Now I cannot install or uninstall Installation Manager or RFT. I think I should dive into the registry and clean IM, but I couldn't find an official resource how to uninstall it manually. Any help is appreciated.

Error message below is in Turkish. To sum up it says IM 1631 is already installed.

[image: IM error]

[image: RFT error]

Comment: You are saying that you can't install Installation Manager. What error do you get when you try that?

Comment: I attached the error capture and my solution. Thanks for your interest Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

First I followed the steps [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21286423). It didn't work by itself. Then I called IBM support and they removed "C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager" folder. Then setup worked.